# Tight upper bound for the degree of the entries of adjugate of polynomial matrix

Tags: matrices, polynomials

(This question was originally asked at Math.SE, where it didn't receive any answers.)

Let $A(x_1, \ldots, x_m)$ be a $n$ x $n$ matrix whose entries are  polynomials on real variables $x_1, \ldots, x_m$, with real coefficients and with degree up to $d$, that is,

$$ A(x_1, \ldots, x_m) = \begin{bmatrix}
p_{11}(x_1, \ldots, x_m) & \cdots & p_{1n}(x_1, \ldots, x_m) \\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
p_{n1}(x_1, \ldots, x_m) & \dots & p_{nn}(x_1, \ldots, x_m)
\end{bmatrix}, $$

with $p_{ij}$ multivariate polynomials and

$$ \max_{i=1,\ldots,n; j=1,\ldots,n} \deg p_{ij} = d. $$

What is a tight upper bound (possibly in function of $m$,$n$ and $d$) for the degree of the entries of the adjugate matrix of $A(x_1, \ldots, x_m)$?

Comment: The entries of the adjugate matrix are polynomials of degree $n-1$ in the entries of $A$ and since the entries of $A$ are polynomials of degree $d$ we get that the entries of the adjugate matrix are polynomials of degree $(n-1)\cdot d$. Equality can be achieved if $A$ is a diagonal matrix with entries $x_1^d$. Do I miss something?

Comment: @user35593 You're right, but I believe it should be $n \cdot d$ instead of $(n-1) \cdot d$. I was thinking that we could do better than $n \cdot d$... Thanks for the answer! :)